# What material is this fake wood? How can I fix what's been chipped off?

Tags: repair, walls

What material is this fake wood? How can I fix the crap that's been chipped off?

[image]

Comment: It’s crappy fake crap paneling. Lowe’s sells some of this crap maybe you can match crap for crap and replace a sheet.   Otherwise clean prime paint over it.

Comment: @Kris Depending on the thickness of the part that came off, might need to sand all the "edges" before priming.

Comment: This is a dumb question but what's the best way to find out what material this is and which would be a best replacement?

Comment: @BrettLarson, find an inconspicuous or easily patched area and cut or drill a hole in it.  Using a hole saw, you will get a circle of material to inspect and shop around with.

Comment: How thick is that area it could be a veneer and it can also be a paper product, it looks like pine , but if a paper it may be better to make a wainscoting to hide the lower level. Is their a sink or tub on the other side of that wall? Stopping what caused the damage in the first place is going to be job #1.